# Cannot get latest value when subscribing to the emitting Publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I have a listener that is registered/deregistered whenever user logs in and out. I have something analogous to the following code,

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class X : ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: String? = nil
    
    func setData() {
        data = "DATA"
    }
}

let x = X()
var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()
x.$data.sink { v1 in  // I need to add .receive(on:) here
    print(v1)
    if v1 != nil {
        x.$data.sink { v2 in
            print(v2) // Why is this nil
        }.store(in: &store)
    }
}.store(in: &store)

x.setData()
```

I thought that `v2` will be `"DATA"`, but it isn't. I need to do a `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` in the outer subscription to get them both to receive the "after" state.

My working theory is that the value isn't written after all the handlers are called, by I don't know how to verify it let alone if it's correct.

Why is `receive(on:)` necessary here?

> I know I could've used `flatMap`, but I didn't use it because I my state is delivered way too late, and I need to unsubscribe to the inner mapped publisher before the sign out code runs to avoid permission issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is a pretty subtle behavior.

The expression `x.$data` evaluates to a [`Published.Publisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published/publisher). When you subscribe to a `Published.Publisher`, it publishes its current value immediately, and then each time the `Published` property receives a new value, the publisher publishes the new value **before** the new value is stored in the property.

This behavior is documented in the [`Published` reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published):

> When the property changes, publishing occurs in the property’s `willSet` block, meaning subscribers receive the new value before it’s actually set on the property.

This means when you call `x.setData()`, the outer subscription receives the new value (`"DATA"`) in `v1`, but `x.data` at that point still evaluates to `nil`. And when you create the inner subscription to `x.$data`, it immediately publishes its **currently stored value**, which is still `nil`.